# Unexpected value for option `hidelinks'(hyperref) is ignored

Tags: hyperref

The lines

```
\hypersetup{hidelinks=true}
```

raises the error

> Unexpected value for option `hidelinks` (`hyperref`) is ignored

However, `hidelinks` is an option offered by `hyperref`. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The `hidelinks` option doesn't expect a value; the correct way to use the option is just:

```
\hypersetup{hidelinks}
```

do not put `=true`.